# VBNC compile errors

Tags: vb.net, mono

I've just installed mono complete, mono-vb and associated libraries, it all appears to be there.

I've written the simplest of vb examples:

```vb
print "Hello, this is a test"
end
```

but vbnc gives me an error "Expected identifier" for each line. I've tested with more lines of code and I get an error for each line in my file.

What am I missing?

Comment: `print "Hello, this is a test"` is not valid. For one, the `Print` method writes to a file (old legacy vb6 method) and requires a file id, not a string as the first argument. Plus VB subroutine calls now require parenthesis around arguments, while they didn't pre-.NET but Mono is for .NET of course. I don't have any experience in Mono but the c# examples are all complete programs with `void Main()` and curly braces etc., and I don't see any samples running a script, such as you are trying

Comment: For multi-platform support, you should look into .NET Core. I am not aware of any argument for Mono over .NET Core in 2022, but like I said, I don't have any experience in Mono...

Comment: @djv I thought the `Print` statement would write to console if not specified as going to a file.

Comment: @Craig [Debug.Print](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.print?view=net-6.0) writes to the console. [FileSystem.Print](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.print?view=net-6.0) comes from Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll / Microsoft.VisualBasicCore.dll (Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace), `FileSystem` being a module so the scope of `Print` is global. `Print` would need its first argument as the FileNumber (not string) - this is carried over from vb6 to .NET similar to `Val`, `CallByName`, `MsgBox`, etc.

Comment: @djv I meant in VB6, not .NET.  Actually, as I recall, there is a `Print` member function in forms that will write the text into the window, which I think was meant to be analogous to the older console print (which would probably still be what you would get in a main module / console app).

Comment: @Craig I don't remember anything like that. But here is the [Print](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/printstatement) I was referring to. Either way, Mono doesn't deal with vb6